# jquery force delay inside .each loop and trigger click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying hands on some automation , I know there are tools for this , but this is for self learning .
My aim is to iterate the pagination bubbles at the page bottom and trigger click() for 'a' tag.If a bubble is active , find next bubble and click it. The delay part is not happening , tried `setTimeout()` and `delay()` as below .

[image]

```
$('div[class="some-class"]').find('a').each(function(index, item) {
    console.log($(this).text());
    if ($(this).hasClass('Pagination__active')) {
        console.log('yeah active');
        $(this).next().click();
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                //do something special
            }, 3000);

    }
    $(this).delay(3000).addClass('position');
});
```

This is the console out , without any delay , new to client side coding , please guide me .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
$('div[class="some-class"]').find('a').each(function(index, item) {
  var $this = $(this)
  var $next = $this.next()

  setTimeout(
    function() {
      console.log($this.text());
      if ($this.hasClass('Pagination__active')) {
        console.log('yeah active');
        $this.click(clicked($next));
        console.log("do something")
        return
      }
      console.log("notactive")
    }, (index) * 3000);
});

function clicked(el) {
  el.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class">
  <a class="Pagination__active">Active</a>
  <a class="">!Active</a>
  <a class="">!Active</a>
  <a class="">!Active</a>
  <a class="">!Active</a>
  <a class="">!Active</a>
  <a class="Pagination__active">Active</a>
  <a class="">!Active</a>
  <a class="">!Active</a>
  <a class="">!Active</a>
</div>
```

Comment: delay is working but $this.next().click(); is not happening !

Comment: @sajanyamaha You can try it again. I updated it. Didn't change much, seems like its working

Comment: actualy I made a small change and it worked , $this.next()[0].click();

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) the `delay`-function only works for existing queues like the effects-queue and i guess `addClass(...)` and `removeClass(...)` are not part of that. All kinds of jQuery-animations (like `animate(...)`, `slideUp(...)`, etc.) are part of the effect-queue (which is the default queue for delay).

So for your case you should use the usual timeout.

Thus your code can be rewritten as

```
$('div.some-class a').each(function(index, item) {
    console.log($(this).text());
    if ($(this).hasClass('Pagination__active')) {
        console.log('yeah active');
        $(this).next().click();
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                //do something special
            }, 3000);

    }
    setTimeout(()=>$(this).addClass('position'), 3000);
});
```

Notice: By using the lambda-notation of the function the context (`this`) remains the same as in the surrounding block (e.g. it does not create an additional closure).

Comment: No difference , no delay seen .

Comment: no delay of what? Maybe the click is what immediately changes the things that you want delayed?